# For double outputs in data table, how to move second or more outputs to new line with same index

Tags: unix, sed

I have a data set that contains two fields, x and y. It is possible for x to have more than one output, y. For example:

> x1,y11,y12,y13,...,y1n
>
> x2,y21
>
> x3,y31,y32
>
> ...

And I would like to manipulate the data so that it looks like:

> x1,y11
>
> x1,y12
>
> x1,y13
>
> ...
>
> x1,y1n
>
> x2,y21
>
> x3,y31
>
> x3,y32
>
> ...

I'm attempting to do this with `sed`. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/(([^,]*),[^,]*),/\1\n\2,/;P;D' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk):

```
awk -F"," '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i++) print $1","$(i) }' input.txt
```

Separate the fields by `,` and loop over all fields in a line, starting from the second one, ending by the last one (`NF` = number of fields) and print always the first field and the i'th field.

Comment: +1 but I'd set/use OFS and there's no need to parenthesize $i: `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $1,$i}' file`

Comment: This is assuming that for each line there are k fields. The number of fields is not uniform for each line. There's no way to predetermine this either.

Comment: No, it's not, `NF` is the number of fields for each line.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand but when I run the following awk -F"," '{ for (i=2; i<=10; i++) print $1","$i }' test.csv I receive 9 outputs per xi which is not what I'm looking for. Instead, the number of lines for each xi should be determined by the number of outputs associated with that xi.

Comment: Maybe you should use `NF`, and not `10`, as it has been in my answer all along.